# Get all page ids linked to a given Wikipedia page

Tags: web-crawler, wikipedia, wikimedia

I am trying to use the Wikimedia public APIs for accessing the English Wikipedia database.

I would like to have a way to obtain all the page ids linked to a given page.

If I do like this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=computer&format=xml

I am only able to obtain the page id of the 'computer' page.

I know I could parse for the 'href' tags inside that page and make n queries, but it is not very efficient.

Can I achieve this through APIs alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for [the `backlinks` module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aBacklinks).

With that, you can do something like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&bltitle=computer&list=backlinks&format=xml

Also, the API uses paging, so you'll most likely need to add `&bllimit=max` to the query and then make [follow-up requests](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Continuing_queries) to get the remaining pages.